# How to remove active background color: orange state in WordPress when using custom link and pages in navbar?

Tags: wordpress

I made a nav menu in WordPress using custom link and pages from admin dashboard. The problem is when I click on page link it works fine and when I click on custom link the background color of all custom link becomes highlighted to color orange. But I want one custom link to remain active with background color orange on one custom link clicked. When I put http://localhost/auction/#blogs the link gets background color highlighted to orange and when I change the link to only #blogs its only works for one page but difficult to redirect to from page to custom page.

I tried all ways to resolve the problem. How can I resolve this issue?

working link:
[image: working link]

Not working links ie. many links highlighted its all custom links :
[image: Not working links ie. many links highlighted its all custom links]

Comment: share some code css + html or url to your page, no1 can tell you what is wrong without seeing the code ...

Comment: Angel Deykov i can't share the code because its a general cutomisation  from admin panel in wordpress dashboard. I think it might be css issue. Can tell me is it css issue or not ?  if not then how to resolve this ?

Comment: i am working on local server.

Comment: Probably css issue, check your code in the debugger and see if all the HTML elements + classes of your working page links are the same as the links that are not working properly. Maybe you can take a screenshot from your debugger showing the structure of 1 working and 1 not working link.

Comment: ok  i will try ! if not resolve then i share screenshot.